# Source to download microsoft visual c++ 9.0 for python 2.7

Tags: windows, python-2.7, visual-c++, compiler-errors, conda

I've encountered a problem whilst trying to install "fa2" (forceatlas2) package onto a conda environment. In my case fa2 is just one of many packages needed, but it's the only one giving me trouble. I also specifically need python 2.7 for the packages, so using newer version is not an option. The error I'm getting is:  `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required. Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27`. As far as I could find, c++ version 9.0 is no longer supported or maintained (the link doesn't lead anywhere). I've checked visual studio tools, but it doesn't have the needed build either. I've also seen several similar questions on the forums but they're dealing with different windows versions so I didn't find much help. I'm on windows 11 if that's any help. Has anyone figured out a way to downgrade visual c++ version and if yes, is it possible to run multiple versions of c++ compiler on the same system, as I'm running different python versions on different anaconda environments. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `conda install vc=9`? Nothing in Conda should need external installs.

Answer (score 0):

Download Visual c++ version 9.0 from the below website:
https://web.archive.org/web/20190720195601/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=44266 and try to install fa2 using pip install fa2. I was able to install fa2 on [my conda environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfrKa.png) -  python2.7

[test for fa2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xv0GJ.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).